# what is the best way to interpret the following return statement in data structure?

Tags: c, data-structures

`(p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node{x, p->prev, p})` is a return statement in C++ code snippet. It is used to insert a new node in a list. I do not quite understand how could have two equal operators in one single statement here.

Comment: At least this isn't C.

Comment: It isn't about the operator keyword either.

Comment: What is `iterator`, `prev`, `next`,`Node` ? How on earth you except people to answer this atleast w.r.t. C ?

Comment: Whoever wrote this code needs to be smacked. Hard.

Comment: please see the discussion below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

- This is a doubly linked list.
- `iterator` is a class.
- `Node` is also a class.
- `x` is the value to be inserted.
- `Node` is an aggregate that has three data members in the order `value`, `prev`, `next`, or alternatively has a constructor that takes three parameters in this order.
- `p` is a pointer to the `Node` that the new node should go before.

On these assumptions:

- `new Node{ x, p->prev, p }` `new`s up a new Node, setting its value to `x`, its previous node as `p->prev`, and its next node as `p`. It returns a pointer to this new node.
- `p->prev->next = /*...*/` sets `next` of `p->prev` - i.e., the node previously before `p` - to point to this freshly created node. The value of this expression is the value assigned (formally, it's an lvalue referring to `p->prev->next` that is then converted to an rvalue, i.e., has the stored value read), which is the pointer to the new node.
- `p->prev = /* ... */` finally makes `p->prev` also point to this new node as well. The result of this expression is again the pointer to the new node. The end result is that the new node is inserted before `p`.
- Finally, `iterator(/* ... */)` constructs a iterator pointing to the new node, and `return` returns it to the caller.

Code like this shouldn't be used. It may look "cute", but it's difficult to read and understand, and my first reaction when I read it is "are you sure it's not undefined behavior"? It took me a few moments to convince myself that the behavior is well-defined (in C++11, at least).

Comment: sorry for the confusing. this is from a course note in data structure in c. I haven't noticed that the origin of source code writting in c++. will revise the searching key.   in addition to the insertion of new Node x, it seems that why we don't define the prev->p